# Mocking a bit stream reader with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am currently debugging a rather complicated algorithm that fixes errors in a bit stream. A `BitReader` interface is quite simple, and the main reading method is like this:

```
/**
  Reads bits from the stream.
  @param length number of bits to read (<= 64)
  @return read bits in the least significant bits
*/
long read(int length) throws IOException;
```

The objective is to test whether `BitStreamFixer` actually fixes the stream (in a way that is too hard to describe here). Basically I need to provide “broken” inputs to it and test whether its output is as correct as it can be (some inputs can't be fixed completely), like this:

```
BitStreamFixer fixer = new BitStreamFixer(input);
int word1 = fixer.readWord();
int word2 = fixer.readWord();
// possibly a loop here
assertEquals(VALID_WORD1, word1);
assertEquals(VALID_WORD2, word2);
// maybe a loop here too
```

Now, the `BitStreamFixer` class accepts an instance of `BitReader`. When unit testing the fixer, I obviously need one such instance. But where do I get one? I have two obvious options: either give it a real implementation of `BitReader` or mock it.

The former option is not really appealing because it would create a dependency on another object which has nothing to do with the class being tested. Moreover, it's not *that* easy because existing `BitReader` implementations read form input streams, so I'll need either a file or somehow prepared byte array, which is a tedious thing to do.

The latter option looks better and fits the usual unit testing approach. However, since I'm not even supposed to know what arguments the fixer will give to `read`, mocking it is not easy. I'll have to go with `when(bitReader.read(anyInt())).thenAnswer(...)` approach, implementing a custom answer that will create a lot of bit-fiddling logic to spoon-feed the object under test with proper bits in chunks of whatever size it asks for. Considering that bit streams I'm working with have rather complicated higher-level structure, it's not easy. And introducing logic in unit tests also doesn't smell good.

What do you think, is there any other option? Or maybe one of these can be improved in a way I fail to notice?

Comment: How does the `BitStreamFixer` and the output of `read()` relate to each other? Creating an anonymous instance of `BitReader` instead of mocking will make it easier to affect the logic of the output, and it won't be a dependency to a *real* class.

Comment: @Kayaman, I've edited the question a little bit to explain further. The idea is that `BitStreamFixer` is a kind of bit stream filter. Creating an anonymous class would be no different from mocking, only worse—because I'd have to implement all methods (not shown and not relevant to the test), and at the same time still provide a reasonable implementation of `read()`. The problem is that it feels too complicated to be a part of a unit test.

Comment: I would go with a _real_ `BitReader` and feed it with a `ByteArrayInputStream`.  Unit testing does not have to be about treating every class in isolation.

Comment: Alternatively, how many methods from `BitReader` does your fixer actually use? If it's a small subset maybe there's another abstraction that you're missing that would make it easier to provide a test double?

Comment: I'd really expect an interface called `BitReader` to have one or two methods anyway.

Comment: It's not a problem of abstraction. It has about 8 methods, but only 3 of them are used by the fixer. 2 of them are easily mocked, it's just `read()` that I'm struggling with. Thing is, creating a byte array is not easier than mocking `read()` because I don't have a `BitWriter` class. So if I'm going to have complicated logic, why not just put it in the mocked method instead of creating unnecessary dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Write, test, and use a clear reusable test helper.**

In a general sense, in unit testing, you're supposed to *establish confidence in a system by watching it successfully interact with systems that you DO have confidence in*. Of course you also want the system to be fast, deterministic, and easy to read/modify, but ultimately those come secondary to the assertion that your system work.

You've listed two options:

- Use a mock `BitReader`, where you have enough confidence in predicting your system's interactions that you can set up the entire "when A then B" conversation. Mocking can be pretty easy when you have a small API surface of independent methods, like an RPC layer, but mocking can be very difficult when you have a stateful object with unpredictable method calls. Mocking is further useful to deterministically stub nondeterministic systems, like external servers or pseudorandom sources, or systems that don't exist yet; none of those is the case for you.

  Because your `read` method can take a wide variety of parameters, each of which is valid and changes your system's state, then it's probably not a smart idea to use mocking here. Unless the order of calls that `BitStreamFixer` makes to `BitReader` is deterministic enough to make part of its contract, a mock `BitReader` will likely result in a brittle test: one that breaks when the implementation changes even if the system is perfectly functional. You'll want to avoid that.

  Note that mocking should never yield "complicated logic", only complicated set-up. You're using mocks to avoid using real logic in your tests.
- Use a real `BitReader`, which sounds like it will be painful and opaque to construct. This is probably the most realistic solution, though, especially if you've already finished writing and testing it.

  You worry about "introducing new dependencies", but if your BitReader implementation exists and is *fast, deterministic, and well-tested*, then you shouldn't feel any worse about using it than using a real ArrayList or ByteArrayInputStream in your test. It sounds like the only real problem here is that creating the byte array would make it hard to maintain your test, which is a valid consideration.

In the comments, though, the real answer comes through: Build the `BitWriter` you're missing.

```
@Test public void shouldFixBrokenStream() {
  BitReader bitReader = new StreamBitReader(BitWriter.create()
      .pushBits(16, 0x8080)
      .pushBits(12, 0x000)   // invalid 12-bit sequence
      .pushBits(16, 0x8080)
      .asByteArrayInputStream());
  BitStreamFixer fixer = new BitStreamFixer(bitReader);
  assertEquals(0x80808080, fixer.read(32));
}

/** Of course, you could skip the BitReader yourself, and just make a new one. */
@Test public void shouldFixBrokenStream_bitReader() {
  BitReader bitReader = new InMemoryBitReader();
  bitReader.pushBits(16, 0x8080);
  bitReader.pushBits(12, 0x000);   // invalid 12-bit sequence
  bitReader.pushBits(16, 0x8080);

  BitStreamFixer fixer = new BitStreamFixer(bitReader);
  assertEquals(0x80808080, fixer.read(32));
}
```

This is more readable than constructing an opaque bitstream offline and copy-pasting it into your test (particularly if well-commented), less brittle than mocks, and *much more testable itself* than an anonymous inner class (or Answer-based version of the same). It is also likely that you can use a system like that across multiple test cases, and possibly even multiple tests.

Comment: Great. This is the kind of answer I've been hoping for. I'm mocking bit streams right now (turned out to be easier than I thought), but this solution is definitely better. Only I don't need just a bit writer (it's easy to implement). I'll also need some helper that will push appropriate bit sequences to the writer (because a valid test case must contain at least several hundreds of 10-bit words, otherwise the fixer won't be able to fix anything). But that can be created and tested too, and moreover, it can be used outside tests as well!